# Printer in a AD double side print problem

Tags: network-printer, active-directory

ive got a printer in my Active directory but its standard set to double sided printing but the problem is the printer doesnt support that so you have to switch it manualy

Ive found the setting for the user but it is automatically set to the original value if you reboot
Where can i find the setting in the active directory ? 
the printer is a :HP Color LaserJet CP1510 Series PCL 6

(its possible that there is a script for this but i dont know where to look)

Answer (score 2):

In AD users and computers, search for the printer by its network name (Right click on your domain, choose "Find..." and change "Users, Contacts, and Groups" to "Printers". Right-click on the printer in question and go to its properties. Check the general tab for "Printing Preferences" - here you should be able to change it to 1-sided printing.